# SQL-Server Group consecutive rows differing by certain value , and calculate the interval

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, grouping

I have this table (MachineLog)

```
ID      BeltBit    timeStamp
------------------------------------------
4561      0        2014 03 10 07:56:03.953
4562      0        2014 03 10 07:56:04.370
4563      0        2014 03 10 07:56:04.960
4564      0        2014 03 10 13:25:33.833
4565      1        2014 03 10 13:27:12.113
4566      1        2014 03 10 13:27:51.203
4567      0        2014 03 10 13:54:08.727
4568      1        2014 03 10 13:56:16.523
4569      1        2014 03 10 13:56:39.260
4570      1        2014 03 10 13:56:39.580
```

I would like to build a query to get this result :

```
StartID   EndID   BeltBit   StartStamp                EndStamp                Interval (in sec)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4561      4564       0      2014 03 10 07:56:03.953   2014 03 10 13:27:12.113    19869
4565      4566       1      2014 03 10 13:27:12.113   2014 03 10 13:54:08.727     1616
4567      4567       0      2014 03 10 13:54:08.727   2014 03 10 13:56:16.523      128
4568      4570       1      2014 03 10 13:56:16.523   2014 03 10 13:56:39.580       23
```

I would like to group by beltbit (all of the consecutive with same beltbit state) and calculate their intervals ...

**Please note:** this table contains millions of records so multiple joins will be extremely slow.

I found such query using sql-2012 LAG and LEAD functions **Please let me know if there is any enhancements**

> ```
>   ;   WITH Level1 
>    AS ( SELECT ID , 
>                BeltBit , 
>                timeStamp AS EventDateTime , 
>                LAG(BeltBit, 1, null) 
>                   OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 
>                      ORDER BY timestamp ) AS LastEvent , 
>                LEAD(BeltBit, 1, null) 
>                   OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 
>                      ORDER BY timestamp) AS NextEvent 
>                          FROM MachineLog ),
> ```
>
> Level2

```
   AS ( SELECT ID , 
               BeltBit , 
               EventDateTime , 
               LastEvent , 
               NextEvent 
        FROM   Level1 
        WHERE  NOT ( BeltBit = 0 
                     AND LastEvent = 0
                   ) 
           AND NOT ( BeltBit = 1 
                     AND NextEvent = 1 
                   ) 

      ),
 Level3 
   AS ( SELECT ID , 
               BeltBit , 
               EventDateTime , 
               DATEDIFF(second, EventDateTime, 
                        LEAD(EventDateTime) 
                           OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 
                              ORDER BY EventDateTime )) AS Seconds 
        FROM Level2 
       ) 

       select * from Level3
```

Comment: Multiple joins will only be slow if you don't have the correct indexes, so requiring Table Scans. Tuning involves creating the correct indexes.

Comment: I think it can be solved using partition without using joins